# Apache vs Nginx for running a multi-tenant SaaS

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, multi-tenant, saas

I am currently working on developing a multi-tenant SaaS application, that will be handling a lot of real-time requests for geolocation, tracking , and chat features, etc. For multiple SaaS customers, with multiple users and multiple customers themselves.

Currently running on LEMP Ubuntu 20.04.

I've spent a couple hours with my rubber duck on this topic and we have decided to reach out to the community.

My concern is the amount of requests that the server will be getting and then also the amount of dynamic content that will be served.

Seeing as Apache uses 1 thread per request, couldn't this cause a huge bottleneck and overload the box?

Comment: apache or nginx as a frontend, ok, but what about backend? What kind of application is it? Language? Stack? Load profile? How many connections per period of time, do you need `keep-alive`s, etc.?

Comment: Running on LEMP Ubuntu 20.04. Using the Laravel 8 framework. I'm not sure of the load profile yet, or an estimate of connections per period of time. I'm thinking keep-alive's will be necessary or best for some of the features.

Comment: it's hard to guess your load profile if you don't know it by yourself, but try php-fpm as a backend with nginx if you more or less familiar with it, otherwise choose default apache + mod-php

Comment: I'm going to stick with my strong point which is apache, was just looking for some input and some brainstorming. Thanks for the guidance.